# Add migration, update database may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Patient entity which has one PatientFile entity and the PatientFile entity has 3 properties with one Physiotherapist.

```
public class PatientFile 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public Physiotherapist IntakeDoneBy { get; set; }
        public int? IntakeDoneById { get; set; }
        public Physiotherapist Supervisor { get; set; }
        public int? SupervisorId { get; set; }
        public Physiotherapist Physiotherapist { get; set; }
        public int? PhysiotherapistId { get; set; }
}

 public class Physiotherapist
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

My onModelCreate looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
           .HasOne(p => p.PatientFile)
           .WithOne(pf => pf.Patient)
           .HasForeignKey<PatientFile>(p => p.PatientId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PatientFile>()
            .HasOne<Physiotherapist>(pf => pf.IntakeDoneBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(pf => pf.IntakeDoneById)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PatientFile>()
            .HasOne<Physiotherapist>(pf => pf.Physiotherapist)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(pf => pf.PhysiotherapistId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PatientFile>()
            .HasOne<Physiotherapist>(pf => pf.Supervisor)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(pf => pf.SupervisorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            }
```

But after adding a migration and update database i get the error:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_PatientFile_Physiotherapists_PhysiotherapistId' on table 'PatientFile' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.**

i don't know what i'm doing wrong, cause i have specified the on delete actions. but i get this error every time no matter what i try

Comment: Any collection navigation property (like `ICollection<PatientFile>` or similar) in `Physiotherapist` class not shown here?

Comment: Physiotherapist does not have a navigation property like `ICollection<PatientFile>`

Comment: The empty `WithMany()` could be a cause.. If you define those navigation properties (one for each shown here), it might fix the issue.

Comment: So i would add `ICollection<PatientFile> PhysiotherapistOfPatientsFiles` and `ICollection<PatientFile> SupervisorOfPatientsFiles`  and `ICollection<PatientFile> IntakeDoneOfPatientsFiles`  to the `Physiotherapist` class ?

Comment: There is no need to define such collections (empty `WitMany()` is perfectly fine). The problem would be if you do have such collections, but not map them inside `HasMany(e => e.SomeCollection)`, hence my previous question.

Comment: Yeah i thought so too, i don't want/need a navigational propperty from Physiotherapist towards PatientFile

Comment: I can however confirm that the issue **does not** reproduce with the provided code (after commenting out `Patient` related members since you didn't provide that class). So there must be something else not shown here (believe me, there *is* always something people skip in questions thinking it is not important, while in fact it is). Try reproducing in a clean new project with just the code from the post, or provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I have Deleted all my migrations and Database tables, and started from scratch. i made a new Initial migration and updated the database and got no Errors.